# How to access webservice hosted in lIS from LAN connected Other PC?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, ipconfig

I have created one webservice which I have hosted in my IIS, now I want to access or call that webservice from LAN connected PC.

So please help me out.

Things I have tried are :

Ping  to check connectivity

Using IpAddress I tried to access it from other PC - Errors I have got like -

1. Connection timeout
2. Unable to connect host

e.g : `http://192.168.100.157/NewWebservice/WebService1.asmx`

Comment: All computers are located in one LAN and are using IP's 192.168.100.*** right?

Comment: what step did you follow to host the application on your local system?

Comment: can you browse to the webservice using localhost from the server?
can you browse to the IIS installation from the LAN either by IP or Hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding following code in config file:

```
<client>
<endpoint address="http://192.168.100.157/NewWebservice/WebService1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="ClassABC" bindingConfiguration ="httpBinding"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IABC" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open port 80 in Windows Firewall (built in) or any other firewall solution installed on that IIS machine.